# Add NFC virtual card dynamically on button click

Tags: android, nfc, hce

I am working on HCE based App that will require payment through NFC at POS terminal.

I have followed the HCE article on android developers site and I am able to add the banner for card during installation through below code :

```
<host-apdu-service   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="true"
android:apduServiceBanner="@drawable/servicebanner">

<aid-group android:category="payment"
           android:description="@string/paymentGroup" >
    <aid-filter ... />
</aid-group>
</host-apdu-service>
```

But I want to add the banner when the user clicks on **ADD CARD button** in my app.

Can we add the banner image dynamically on button click ?

Thanks